# Unsupervised learning algorithms to detect anomaly in waves.

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, data-analysis, wave-equation, data-mining

I have a sample of graphs (more than 10000...).
that look like in the image below:
[image]

I am searching for an unsupervised learning algorithms that can help me to detect anomalous observations.

Here what I suggest for beginning: for every observation I have a collection of points $(x,y)$. With this collection, I find Fourier series with regression (I compute coefficients with the base $\{1,\sin(x),\cos(x),\sin(2x),\cos(2x)\dots\}$).
Now I have a set of coefficients instead of waves.

Somebody have an idea how to detect anomaly?

Comment: Too broad/ambitious

Comment: can you explain the figures? are they all normal obsevations or? In other words what do you call as anomalous observation?

Comment: The figures are waves of analogue data (i.e volts of some machine). Anomalus observation are observations that very unsimilar (with specific algorithms that i look for) to the train data.

Answer (score 1):

FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) each wave
to get its
[Power spectral density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density)
(PSD).
Your "anomalous" waves *may* transform to a PSD like that of white noise,
flat (however I'm no expert).

To refine this, make a
[Linear classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_classifier).
Train it manually: pick out anomalous 10 ? out of 100 ? waves by hand and eye,
and make a linear classifier with e.g.
[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) 
to separate the 10 from the 90 / 10k from 90k.
Added 1 Dec:
[Spectral flatness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_flatness)
is a measure of how noise-like a signal is;
it's easy to implement, and may be adequate for your task.

(I'd suggest asking over on [dsp.stackexchange.com](http://dsp.stackexchange.com),
with tag Matlab or Python too.
Moderators, move the question ?)

Comment: I use sin/cos to transfer the waves to data that i can wotk with.